# Setting/Defining Extension Configuration (if one does not want to use VSCode's default settings/configuration) using package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, vscode-extensions, package.json

Is it possible to **set the configurations or settings of any extension using package.json file** without having to go to Preferences->Settings->Extensions and making the changes in configuration for that particular extension. It would be great if this can be automated and done through package.json file.

Comment: you can do it with JavaScript, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration

Comment: Is this for an extension you are writing?  If so , see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration.  If not, I guess you could access and edit any extension's package.json file to include whatever defaults for their configurations you want.  But these changes would be lost if that extension got updated.

Comment: Yes, I want exactly the second one. I am not writing extension, I just want to change the settings of already existing extension. How can I access extension's package.json file? Is it possible to do that? @Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions to the above mentioned query:

1. The most practical and logical solution is to use "configurationDefaults contribution point" to override the default configuration of extensions set by Visual Studio Code. Please refer to [configuration defaults override](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_configuration-defaults-overrides).
2. The second solution is to access package.json file of that particular extension by going to .vscode folder in your home directory (this option makes permanent changes on the disk).